# Hadoop Job stuck at map 0% reduce 0%

Tags: hadoop, reducers, mappers

I am running a hadoop job which gets stuck at at "map 0% reduce 0%". More specifically, the mappers are all in the "STARTING" state and never seem to actually start executing.

I've tried looking at the logs but didn't really see anything other than some deprecation messages. I'm not exactly sure what to look for and was wondering if anyone has any recommendations?

EDIT 1:

stderr logs:

```
 26, 2013 1:15:32 AM com.google.inject.servlet.InternalServletModule$BackwardsCompatibleServletContextProvider get
WARNING: You are attempting to use a deprecated API (specifically, attempting to @Inject ServletContext inside an eagerly created singleton. While we allow this for backwards compatibility, be warned that this MAY have unexpected behavior if you have more than one injector (with ServletModule) running in the same JVM. Please consult the Guice documentation at http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Servlets for more information.
Dec 26, 2013 1:15:33 AM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory register
INFO: Registering org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.webapp.JAXBContextResolver as a provider class
Dec 26, 2013 1:15:33 AM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory register
INFO: Registering org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.GenericExceptionHandler as a provider class
Dec 26, 2013 1:15:33 AM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory register
INFO: Registering org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.webapp.AMWebServices as a root resource class
Dec 26, 2013 1:15:33 AM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.9 09/02/2011 11:17 AM'
Dec 26, 2013 1:15:33 AM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory getComponentProvider
INFO: Binding org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.webapp.JAXBContextResolver to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "Singleton"
Dec 26, 2013 1:15:33 AM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory getComponentProvider
INFO: Binding org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.GenericExceptionHandler to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "Singleton"
Dec 26, 2013 1:15:33 AM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory getComponentProvider
INFO: Binding org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.webapp.AMWebServices to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "PerRequest
```

Comment: Can you post the logs here?

Comment: I didn't want to clutter up the thread so I was wondering which logs would be most relevant? Would any of the DataNode, NameNode, SecondaryNameNode, ResourceManager or NodeManager logs be useful? Under userlogs, the container has syslog, stderr and stdout logs as well. stdout is empty but stderr is not. I'll post stderr for now and will edit if there's anything else you think its worth to take a look at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

usually looking at ResourceManager's log can be helpful. look for any exception in its log. if no exception exists, look at NodeManager logs for any exception. inform these possible exceptions here.